# How to avoid multiple frames?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, desktop-application

I am creating a Java desktop application. In this application I have one table. If the user double clicks the row of table, the corresponding data was viewed in another window [frame -> view frame]. The user minimizes the view frame and selects another row in a table. It was again open in a new window [frame].

How to avoid the multiple frame?  I want only one view frame at a time. Suppose the user want to view new data then the old view frame will exit and new view frame will open.

Comment: don't have two JFrames in the first place! But I would say: make the view frame modal.

Comment: Why don't you maintain a single reference to the JFrame ? Singleton pattern?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for links to answers with multiple alternatives - including `CardLayout` and a nested layout (e.g. table in `CENTER` with details in PAGE_END` of a `BorderLayout`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the frame an instance variable. Whenever you have to display a new frame, check if it is already displayed and if it is, first close the existing one and then display the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's best if you have a single `JFrame` in your application while all other windows are `JDialog`s.

- Have you considered making the second window modal ?
- Another option would be to have a flag which tells you if the second window is open. If it is, then when the user double clicks another row in the table you just replace the content (instead of creating a new window).

You can set that flag inside the `windowClosed` method of a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html). This `WindowListener` you will then add it to your second window.

- You can see if a `Window` is opened by calling [`Window#isShowing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isShowing%28%29). This is applicable to both `JFrame`s and `JDialog`s.